# Change All Font of PDF file (iTextSharp)

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I'm doing a little program that have to change all fonts of an input pdf file, but for some reason it only changes a few parts of the document. I removed this list of PDFName :

-PdfName.BASEFONT , PdfName.FONT , PdfName.FONTDESCRIPTOR , PdfName.FONTFILE , PdfName.FONTFILE2 , PdfName.FONTFILE3.

I have a little suspect that Im missing some property to delete ... do you guys have some idea?

```
 public static void Changer(PdfDictionary iFile) {
            if (iFile == null) {
                return;
            }

            PdfDictionary xObjects = iFile.GetAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECT);
            if ((xObjects != null)) {
                foreach (PdfName key in xObjects.Keys) {
                Changer(xObjects.GetAsDict(key));
                }

            }

            PdfDictionary fonts = iFile.GetAsDict(PdfName.FONT);

        if (fonts == null) {
                return;
            }

        PdfDictionary singleFont = null;

        foreach (PdfName singleKey in fonts.Keys.ToList()) {

           //PROP DELETE TEST

            singleFont = fonts.GetAsDict(singleKey);
            singleFont.Remove(PdfName.BASEFONT);
            singleFont.Remove(PdfName.FONT);
            singleFont.Remove(PdfName.FONTDESCRIPTOR);
            singleFont.Remove(PdfName.FONTFILE);
            singleFont.Remove(PdfName.FONTFILE2);
            singleFont.Remove(PdfName.FONTFILE3);
            singleFont.Remove(singleKey);

            singleFont.Put(PdfName.BASEFONT, new PdfString("Courier"));
            singleFont.Put(PdfName.FONT, new PdfString("Courier"));
            singleFont.Put(PdfName.FONTDESCRIPTOR, new PdfString("Courier"));
            singleFont.Put(PdfName.FONTFILE, new PdfString("Courier"));
            singleFont.Put(PdfName.FONTFILE2, new PdfString("Courier"));
            singleFont.Put(PdfName.FONTFILE3, new PdfString("Courier"));
            singleFont.Put(singleKey, new PdfString("Courier"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Indeed, the best you can hope for is some very ugly result. Usually, though, you'll get a broken PDF.

Comment: @KJ For some reasson Im gettin trouble in my main app with documents with specific fonts. So I make this program to change that specific fonts to Arial or any generic font. It works with a few documents but isn't a 100% functional. Some documents only get change a few lines. So I remove and "PUT" all those properties (Basefont, font, fontfile ...) but still not a 100% funcional. I guess that I missing some PDFName prop or somethig

Comment: @mkl I know... But is my only chance to make that type of document run ... Is a completly  sidecase

Comment: Maybe you should investigate what exactly in those documents with those specific fonts is the issue. Because for  a sensible font replacement you'll first have to check the existing encoding and encode your replacement likewise. But if that very encoding causes your issues, font replacement won't gain you anything.